# Find strings that occurs in every list

Tags: python

I have three lists and I want to find the strings that occurs in every list. How can I do that in smart and pythonic way?

```
list_a = ['KOMMUN', 'PERIOD', 'ALÖS', 'LAL_12', 'LAL_24', 'AK_TOT', 'PERIOD_Q',
       'andel_lal12_alös', 'andel_lal12_ak', 'andel_lal24_alös',
       'andel_lal24_ak', 'LAN', 'geo']

list_b=[['geo', 'PERIOD', 'ALÖS', 'LAL_12', 'LAL_24', 'AK_TOT', 'PERIOD_Q',
       'andel_lal12_alös', 'andel_lal12_ak', 'andel_lal24_alös',
       'andel_lal24_ak', 'LAN_namn', 'ROW_REGION']]

list_c= ['geo', 'PERIOD', 'ALÖS', 'LAL_12', 'LAL_24', 'AK_TOT', 'PERIOD_Q',
       'andel_lal12_alös', 'andel_lal12_ak', 'andel_lal24_alös',
       'andel_lal24_ak']


list_final=['geo', 'PERIOD', 'ALÖS', 'LAL_12', 'LAL_24', 'AK_TOT', 'PERIOD_Q',
       'andel_lal12_alös', 'andel_lal12_ak', 'andel_lal24_alös',
       'andel_lal24_ak']
```

Comment: Looks like a job for [sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `set.intersection`:

```
final_list = list(set(list_a) & set(list_b[0]) & set(list_c))
```

Output:

```
['PERIOD', 'ALÖS', 'LAL_24', 'geo', 'andel_lal12_ak', 'LAL_12', 'andel_lal24_alös', 'AK_TOT', 'PERIOD_Q', 'andel_lal12_alös', 'andel_lal24_ak']
```

Comment: Note to the op: you might not even need the cast to list (e.g. if you just want to test membership).  Although it's likely trivial unless your intersection is enormous or you do this a lot, neither of which seems likely.